# Running thousands of updateMany statements against mongodb gives error "Bufbuilder attempted to grow() to x bytes, past the 64MB limit"

Tags: sql, mongodb, robo3t

I am attempting to run ~17000 updateMany() statements to add a value to each document that matches the filter. So 17000 of these:

```
db.mycollection.updateMany({documentIdentifier:'cb804174-dcc0-4059-a7c2-25f6e462f878'},{$addToSet: {'myArray': {id:'f6e5bf80-5d7b-4920-9f69-ecf83a7b919c', type:'newTypeId', name:'Coffee Machine'}}});
```

I am using Robo 3t to execute these statements. It always gives the error:
"Failed to execute script. Error: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 67108865, past the 64MB limit." when I try to run all 17000 statements.

However it seems I can run these statements in batches of 1000 successfully.
Is there any way for me to run all 17000 in one go without the above error?

**Notable points:**

- I have tried using db.collection.bulkWrite() and tried setting writeConcern to: { writeConcern : {w:0, j:false}} but this gave the same error.
- I have tried using db.mycollection.update() and setting {multi:true} which probably just does the same as updateMany() anyway.
- After googling a lot it seems that the result object could be the problem? When i run 1000 of these statements I think Robo 3t opens 1000 tabs. One tab for each of the statements run. This is maybe the issue but I have no idea how to solve it.

**Why im doing this:**

I am generating these update statements from SQL. I need values from an SQL database put into each document in a mongodb collection. So I am generating these updates using SQL concat() method. The alternative is me writing a console app that interacts with both databases, im trying to avoid that as it would take longer.

Like so:

```
select a.id as aetid, a.name as assetName, at.Id as at.typeid, at.Name as assetTypeName, 
concat('db.myCollection.updateMany({documentIdentifier:''',lower(a.Id),'''},{$addToSet: {''myArray'': {id:''',lower(at.Id),''', type:''newTypeId'', name:''',at.Name,'''}}});') as UpdateStatement,
concat('db.myCollection.updateMany({documentIdentifier:''',lower(a.Id),'''},{$pull: {''myArray'': {type:''newTypeId''}}});') as RollbackStatement
from Asset as a
join AssetType as at on (at.Id = a.aetTypeId)
```

Not too relevant but in case anyone is curious.